# Removing controller name from Rails URL route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

This is my first Rails project, I am trying to piece things together slowly.

When I'm trying to view the page I generated using `rails g controller <controller> <page>`, I find myself going to `0.0.0.0:3000/controller/page.html`, How can I configure it so that my route file globally allows viewing the page via the page name, rather than controller/page, if no such way exists, then how can I route `controller/page.html` to `/page.html`

I've looked around, and haven't really found any explanation, maybe I'm looking in the wrong places?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `config/routes.rb`:

```
get '/page' => 'controller#action'
```

If your controller is:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def something
  end
end
```

Then `config/routes.rb` would be:

```
get '/page' => 'users#something'
```

For static pages you could want to use `public` folder though, everything you put there is directly accessible, for example `public/qqqqqq.html` would be accessed in `localhost:3000/qqqqqq.html`

Comment: Thanks mate :) Much appreciated, so the mouthed "something" is the part the comes after the # (i.e '<controller>#<method>'?

Answer (score 2):

We've just achieved this by using the `path` argument in `resources` method:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :controller, path: ""
```

For you specifically, you'll want to make something like this:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :static_pages, path: "", only: [:index]
   get :page
   get :other_page
end

#app/controllers/your_controller.rb
def page
end

def other_page
end
```

This will give you routes without the controller name. You'll have to **define this at the end of your routes** (so other paths come first)

Obviously this will form part of a wider routes file, so if it doesn't work straight up, we can refactor!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like this is a static page, so you can do as juanpastas says, or another option is to create a folder under your `app/views` directory to hold these pages. Maybe something like
`app/views/static_pages/the_page.html.erb`

Then in your `config/routes.rb` you can add:

`match '/your_page_name', to: 'static_pages#the_page', via: :get`

Comment: Its not a static page, I have it set to do HTTP request, to web services that I set up, I don't need a DB, but I do need a controller. thanks for the advice though..